# MySQLi Fetch Array returning Null

Tags: php, mysqli

Really don't know whats up here but it's not returning anything on the page.. I am slowly changing everything from MySQL to the new MySQLi

```
<?php
include_once "php_includes/db_conx.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM testimonials ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 32";
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die (mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $testtitle = $row['testtitle'];
   $testbody = $row['testbody'];
   $compowner = $row['compowner'];
   $ownertitle = $row['ownertitle'];
   $compname = $row['compname'];
   $compwebsite = $row['compwebsite'];

   $testsList .= '<div class="gekko_testimonial testimonial gekko_testimonial_speech">  
       <div class="gekko_main"><div class="gekko_headline">' . $testtitle . '</div>
        <p>' . $testbody . '</p>
        </div>
         <div class="speech_arrow"></div>   
         <span class="gekko_who_client_name">' . $compowner . ' of ' . $compname . '</span>
         <span class="gekko_who_job_title">' . $ownertitle . '</span>
         <span class="gekko_who_website">View the Website... <a href="http://' . $compwebsite . '" target="_blank">' . $compwebsite . '</a></span>
      </div>';
 }
?>
```

Any help greatly appreciated! I am also you `<?php echo $testslists; ?>` in my html!
Many thanks
Phillip Dews

Comment: First, prove you connected to the db at all. How would you do that? how do you know it worked?

Answer (score 2):

Your only problem is **insufficient error reporting**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Just add these lines at the top of your code and you will be immediately informed of the exact problem with your code.

Note that on the production server you have to turn displaying errors off and logging on

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` needs connection to be the first parameter. please pay close attention to mysqli functions as many of them required the connection as the first parameter.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
```

Comment: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/285587)

Comment: sorted many thanks All i done was add
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
To it!